# How to detect where my app collapsed in linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging, memory-leaks

HI, i am recently in a project in linux written in C.
This app has several processes and they share a block of shared memory...When the app run for about several hrs, a process collapsed without any footprints so it's very diffficult to know what the problem was or where i can start to review the codes....
well, it could be memory overflown or pointer malused...but i dunno exactly...
Do you have any tools or any methods to detect the problems...
It will very appreciated if it get resolved. thanx for your advice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you start the program, enable core dumps:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

(and make sure the working directory of the process is writeable by the process)

After the process crashes, it should leave behind a `core` file, which you can then examine with `gdb`:

```
gdb /some/bin/executable core
```

Alternatively, you can run the process under `gdb` when you start it - `gdb` will wake up when the process crashes.

Answer (score 3):

You could also run gdb in gdb-many-windows if you are running emacs. which give you better debugging options that lets you examine things like the stack, etc. This is much like Visual Studio IDE.

Here is a useful link

```
http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/02/fancy-debugging-with-gdb.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind is where you need to go next. Chances are that you have a memory misuse problem which is benign -- until it isn't. Run the programs under valgrind and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bmargulies -- Valgrind is absolutely the best tool out there to automatically detect incorrect memory usage. Almost all Linux distributions should have it, so just `emerge valgrind` or `apt-get install valgrind` or whatever your distro uses.

However, Valgrind is hardly the least cryptic thing in existence, and it usually only helps you tell where the program eventually ended up accessing memory incorrectly -- if you stored an incorrect array index in a variable and then accessed it later, then you will still have to figure that out. Especially when paired with a powerful debugger like GDB, however (the `backtrace` or `bt` command is your friend), Valgrind is an incredibly useful tool.

Just remember to compile with the `-g` flag (if you are using GCC, at least), or Valgrind and GDB will not be able to tell you where in the source the memory abuse occurred.